# SQLAlchemy ORM Query encoding

Tags: encoding, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, utf

Folks,

Can you please advise on following. 
I am trying to display values in native format - Cyrillic.

Below is my query

```
db.session.query(items.item_name).join(item_ship, item_ship.item_id == items.id).join(house_shipment, house_shipment.id == item_ship.shipment_id).first();
```

Result: (u'\u041c\u0443\u0436\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u043e\u0431\u0443\u0432\u044c',)

Default collation for table items is set to `utf8_general_ci` and my connection string is following.

```
mysql://root:Abc123@localhost/test?charset=utf8
```

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: looks like cyrillic to me: `map(unicodedata.name, u'\u041c\u0443\u0436\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f')
Out[4]: 
['CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER EM',
 'CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER U',
 'CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ZHE',
 'CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES',
 'CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER KA',
 'CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A',
 'CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER YA']
`

Answer (score 0):

Your encoding is right:

```
>>> print(u'\u041c\u0443\u0436\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u043e\u0431\u0443\u0432\u044c')
Мужская обувь
>>> print(repr(u'Мужская обувь'))
u'\u041c\u0443\u0436\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u043e\u0431\u0443\u0432\u044c'
```

Your main problem that you are getting not a string but object that contains first result row. So you are getting `repr` of object.
Change `.first()` at the end of query to `.scalar()`. [Scalar](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar) will return first column of first row. 
As another variant you may access to row object and extract string from it.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out. I will try to be more descriptive next time.